# Mutiple values testing, how to replace many else if statements?

Tags: java, android, performance, if-statement, android-studio

In my android app, I am testing some strings (that I got back from another activity) to see if they are empty. If not, I build my url from these values, example : (EDITED)

```
    //country only
    if (!fetchData_country.isEmpty() && fetchData_city.isEmpty() && fetchData_pmin.isEmpty() && fetchData_pmax.isEmpty()){
        query_url = URL_PRODUCT + "?" + URL_SEARCH_COUNTRY + id_country + URL_LANGUAGE;
        Log.i("INFO", "Url country only : " + query_url);
    }
    //country & price min
    else if(!fetchData_country.isEmpty() && fetchData_city.isEmpty() && !fetchData_pmin.isEmpty() && fetchData_pmax.isEmpty()) {
        query_url = URL_PRODUCT + "?" + URL_SEARCH_COUNTRY + id_country + "&" + URL_SEARCH_PRICE_MIN + id_pmin + URL_LANGUAGE;
        Log.i("INFO", "Url country & price_min : " + query_url);
    }

    //city & price_min
    else if(fetchData_country.isEmpty() && !fetchData_city.isEmpty() && !fetchData_pmin.isEmpty() && fetchData_pmax.isEmpty()) {
        query_url = URL_PRODUCT + "?" + URL_SEARCH_CITY + id_city + "&" + URL_SEARCH_PRICE_MIN + id_pmin + URL_LANGUAGE;
        Log.i("INFO", "Url city & price_min : " + query_url);
    }

    // country & city & pmin
    else if(!fetchData_country.isEmpty() && !fetchData_city.isEmpty() && !fetchData_pmin.isEmpty() && fetchData_pmax.isEmpty()) {
        query_url = URL_PRODUCT + "?" + URL_SEARCH_COUNTRY + id_country +  "&" + URL_SEARCH_CITY + id_city +  "&" + URL_SEARCH_PRICE_MIN + id_pmin + URL_LANGUAGE;
        Log.i("INFO", "Url country & city & pmin : " + query_url);
    }//many values to test still...
```

I wonder how I can improve these testing parts, thanks for helping !

Comment: @Palcente can u develop a little pls ? It's not very clear, thanks

Comment: !fetchData_pmin.isEmpty() && fetchData_pmin.isEmpty() this does not make sense at all

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi , sorry  !fetchData_pmin.isEmpty() && fetchData_pmax.isEmpty(), beside that my code is working, I'm looking for improvement while testing thx (code edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write something similar to this

```
String query_url = URL_PRODUCT + "?" + (!fetchData_country.isEmpty() ? "URL_SEARCH_COUNTRY + id_country " : "")
            +(!fetchData_country.isEmpty() ? "&":"" )+ (!fetchData_pmin.isEmpty() ? " + URL_SEARCH_PRICE_MIN + id_pmin  " : "")
            +(!fetchData_pmin.isEmpty() ? "&":"" )+ (!fetchData_city.isEmpty() ? " + URL_SEARCH_CITY + id_city  " : "");
```

Comment: With a little adapting, it works fine ! Thank you @user5323999, accepted answer

Comment: Multiple conditions in ternary operators

Comment: hey jay if u find my answer useful please upvote the answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @user5323999, I'm sorry since I'm a newbie in Stack, I dont have enough reputation to do it, but when I will have enough, I will do it for sure ! Thanks again for the help

Comment: like promised, I have enough reputation to upvote now, done ;)